# How to condition SQL WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, where-clause, group-concat

I would like to condition when to GROUP_CONCAT my results. I can't figure out the way how to separate my 'category' and 'condition' results.

```
SELECT d.company_name AS 'organisation name',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag) AS 'category',
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag) AS 'conditions', d.contact_describtion AS 'description', d.tel, d.tel2, d.mobile, d.email, d.email2, d.web, d.web2, d.address, d.town, d.county, d.post_code AS 'post code', IF(d.state = 1, "published", "unpublished") AS 'status',d.contact_page_notes AS 'contact history', d.last_contacted_date AS 'last contacted', d.last_updated_date AS 'last updated'
FROM jds4a_directory d INNER JOIN
     jds4a_tags_resources res
     on d.id = res.resource_id INNER JOIN
     jds4a_tags tag
     on tag.id = res.tag_id
WHERE tag.category = 'condition' OR tag.category = 'category'
GROUP BY res.resource_id
```

[image: Here is my result]

[image: jds4a_tags table]

What I want to achieve is to only display category tags under the category and only display condition tags under conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case`.  You are also returning way too many columns, I think:

```
SELECT d.company_name AS organisation_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN tag.category = 'condition' THEN tag.tag END)) AS categories,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN tag.category = 'category' THEN tag.tag END)) AS conditions
FROM jds4a_directory d INNER JOIN
     jds4a_tags_resources res
     on d.id = res.resource_id INNER JOIN
     jds4a_tags tag
     on tag.id = res.tag_id
WHERE tag.category IN ('condition', 'category')
GROUP BY d.company_name;
```

Notes:

- The `SELECT` columns should be consistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.  Don't overload with extraneous columns.
- `GROUP BY` should match the unaggregated keys/expressions in the `SELECT`.
- Use `IN` instead of a bunch of `OR`s -- easier to maintain, write, and less prone to error.
- Use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The GROUP_CONCAT is missing the closing bracket (in case some want to use this as an example). Apart from that does exactly what i need!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Query:

```
SELECT d.company_name AS 'organisation name',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag.tag) AS 'category',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag1.tag) AS 'conditions', d.contact_describtion AS 'description', d.tel, d.tel2, d.mobile, d.email, d.email2, d.web, d.web2, d.address, d.town, d.county, d.post_code AS 'post code', IF(d.state = 1, "published", "unpublished") AS 'status',d.contact_page_notes AS 'contact history', d.last_contacted_date AS 'last contacted', d.last_updated_date AS 'last updated'
FROM jds4a_directory d 
INNER JOIN  jds4a_tags_resources res
on d.id = res.resource_id 
LEFT JOIN jds4a_tags tag
on tag.id = res.tag_id AND tag.category = 'category'
LEFT JOIN jds4a_tags tag1
on tag1.id = res.tag_id AND tag1.category = 'condition' 
GROUP BY res.resource_id
```

Have not tried this query. But it should work. Basically you need to join on jds4a_tags  table one more time with conditional tag name